# C++ Delete tree item while iterating

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I have a tree-based scene.
Iteration to update all objects is performed like this:

```
void IUpdatableTreeItem::updateTree(float pDt)
{
  updateSelf(pDt); ///< pure virtual

  for (int i = 0; i < (int)d_children.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (auto* pUpdatableChild =
      dynamic_cast<IUpdatableTreeItem*>(d_children[i]))
    {
      pUpdatableChild->updateTree(pDt);
    }
  }
}
```

I update the object via "updateSelf" and then go to it's children to update all of them recursively. "updateSelf" is a pure virtual function and can do everything it wants, including self-deletion, deletion of any child or even own parent.
Deletion is trivial: delete self from the parent's list if any, delete all children recursively and "delete this" in the end.

If I try do delete the current object in the "updateSelf" function - I catch a legit exception on access to d_children.

There is an option (rather poor I think) to mark self as "deleted" intead of direct "delete this" and to check it on every step. We should mark not only the object to be deleted, but also all it's children recursively via some "deleteSelf" function.

```
void IUpdatableTreeItem::updateTree(float pDt)
{
  if (deleted)
    return;

  updateSelf(pDt); /// This contains a call to deleteSelf();

  for (int i = 0; i < (int)d_children.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (auto* pUpdatableChild =
      dynamic_cast<IUpdatableTreeItem*>(d_children[i]))
    {
      if (deleted)
        return;

      pUpdatableChild->updateTree(pDt);

      if (pUpdatableChild.deleted)
        removeChild(pUpdatableChild);
    }
  }
}
```

and then delete all "deleted" object in a parent.

Second option is to delete all marked objects in a second pass (also seems to be not optimal). Both of these options seem ugly to me.

Is there a way to avoid the second pass and to avoid checks on every line?

**UPD:**

Deletion of an item means also the deletion of all it's children. Dtor looks like this:

```
ITreeItem::~ITreeItem()
{
  for (auto child : d_children)
    delete child;
}
```

It means that after deleting the parent I can't refer to the current obj's d_children.

Comment: there is [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), where you can post such questions.

Comment: @GreenTree This would be a bad fit for Code Review the way it's currently phrased. Please take a look at [What not to ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: see what questions are [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at code review, and read last sentence of the question.

Comment: Ok, I rephrased the question to avoid general quiestion.

Comment: @Anton Egorov, if parent is destroyed, what will be with its children.? please, provide more information about your objects architecture.

Comment: @GreenTree, deletion of parent means the deletion of all it's children. It means that by deleting the parent I also delete the current class.
Added UPD to the post.

Comment: @Anton, deleting `this` in member function is a bad idea, because it leads to UB (at least in way you do it), since method continue to be executed at not existing object.

Comment: maybe i have missed something, but why just not to exchange order of self and children visitations in your first case.? probably you are writing something like game engine, yes.?

Comment: @GreenTree, yes, kinda game. Changing the order will not help me in the case when any of children wants to delete it's parent (current object).